# "some notation" or "some notations"?

Tags: grammar

I found two expressions in the English math paper I read, i.e., "some notation" and "some notations". Which one is right? Thanks!

Comment: One is the plural of the other. We cannot tell you which is "right". They might both have been right but you don't allow us to see the sentences where they were used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are acceptable depending on context. "Some notations" refers to an unspecified number or portion of notations, while "some notation" refers to a single, nonspecific and nondescript notation. The latter usage is fairly casual in tone and I would not think it proper for an academic paper, but given we know nothing about the paper or the specific context of these usages that might be an erroneous assumption.

If the context for both of these was a reference to a quantity of notations, then the plural usage is correct. As far as I know, "notations" is the only accepted plural form